# tutorial about configuring jenkins to run tests before git pushing commits

Tags: git, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I have a local git repository, and also have a working jenkins project.

I'd like to hook the jenkins task, so that before pushing any changes to the remote repo the jenkins project gets executed, and if the tests dont's succeed git stops the push

I thought this should be a pretty common scenario, but I've been googling around and I couldn't find a tutorial explaining

Comment: this is the closest I've found so far: http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-AdvancedFeatures

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason that you're not seeing this scenario out in the wild is that it sounds like you're trying to solve a clean code / dirty code separation by using separate *repos* as opposed to separate branches, which is the norm.

Perhaps instead, you have a single remote that Jenkins is listening to, and perhaps is listening to (say) the 'dev' branch.  You push from your local to the remote dev branch.  Jenkins listens, builds when it sees a change, and if it likes what it sees, merges that to 'master'.

Then your dirty code is on the dev branch, separate from the clean code on your master branch.

This is a more conventional way of solving this type of problem.. you'll probably find more support for this model.

Comment: Sorry, to accomplish pushing to different *repos* as your question asks, or to different branches?  If it's the latter, check this out:http://twasink.net/2011/09/20/git-feature-branches-and-jenkins-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-about-broken-builds/.  This is just one possibility but should give the right idea

Answer (score 2):

It is actually a pretty common scenario, but that doesn't mean that will be easy to accomplish.

The best thing to do, as a starting point, is to read the [Jenkins official documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Use+Jenkins).

From there, you can read specific articles, like [this one](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2011/06/30/how-to-automatically-run-unit-tests-from-a-git-push/), that talks about one hook that does something similiar to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could push to a repository Jenkins monitors for changes. As the last build step (i.e. after everything else has succeeded) you could then push the changes to the actual remote repository.